# Warning message in h2o.randomforest using R while predicting

Tags: r, random-forest

```
In my following R code , i am getting an warning message in predicting values in the test data
```

train <- h2o.assign(training,"train.hex")
  test  <- h2o.assign(testing,"test.hex")

```
#####
rf<-h2o.randomForest(
  training_frame = train,
  x = 1:32,
  y = 33,
  ntrees = 50,
  score_each_iteration = T,
  stopping_rounds = 2,
  seed=999999)

    summary(rf)
    predictions<-as.data.frame(h2o.predict(rf,newdata=test))

    submission<-data.frame(unique_id=test$unique_id,target=predictions$predict)

    #Warning message : test/validation dataset column '' has levels not trained on
```

Comment: as there are new levels in test data in some categorical variables,that can be a problem, so how to resolve it

Comment: Please don't cross-post the same question on other stackoverflow sites. I've answered this over at CrossValidated. I suggest you delete it here.